# Prove that $b_n$ converges if $a_n$ converges and $a_n+b_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I’ve been given this assignment and I’m having a really hard time figuring out how to answer it.
I’ve tried proving it in the same way as proving that if $a_n$ converges and $b_n$ converges then $a_n+b_n$ converges, but I got stuck halfway through.

I’d really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it help that if $a_n$ converges then $-a_n$ converges, and then $b_n$=$(a_n+b_n)+(-a_n)$?

Comment: It does. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See also [Help in proving $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n \pm b_n) = a \pm b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737821) and http://mathonline.wikidot.com/limit-sum-difference-laws-for-convergent-sequences#toc1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $L := \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$, $L' := \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n)$.

Suppose that $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq k,$ $|a_n - L| < \varepsilon/2$. There also exists a natural number $k'$ such that for all $n \geq k'$, $|a_n + b_n - L'| < \varepsilon/2$. Can you continue the argument from here?

> Define $K := \text{max}(k, k')$, then for all $n \geq K$ we have that

> \begin{align}|b_n - (L' - L)| &= |(a_n + b_n - L') - (a_n - L)| \\ &\leq |a_n + b_n - L'| + |a_n - L| \\ &< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\ &= \varepsilon. \end{align} This shows that $b_n \to L' - L$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!